# Justify the distance between subsubsection and table[h]

Tags: bibtex

[image: tab]

How can I justify the distance between subsubsection and `table[h]`?

The red region is too big and I want to reduce this distance, how should I do?

Comment: Add the command `\raggedbottom` at the beginning of the document.

Comment: thx you,bro. But it not works well for me....

Comment: note that the bottom two lines of text are at the bottom of the page and at the same point, that is the default `\flushbottom` style, it can only do that by stretching white space and the only stretchy space you have is your red regions. so as commented above you can use `\raggedbottom` so the red regions are not stretched but then the excess space will come at the bottom,.

Comment: @sunnpeng1996 since you have shown no code, you can not expect any very  explicit comments on what to fix. Questions should almost always have a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: @sunnpeng1996 -- Although you've shown no code, it's fairly common for `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` to be used in floats (`table` or `figure`).  This adds extra space in addition to what is provided automatically around floats.  It is better to use `\centering`, which has the same effect without the extra space.